# Export Eclipse project to zip including external libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, libraries

For an assignment I have to export an eclipse project as a zip folder that contains all libraries I used (JfreeChart e.g.). I've been trying to do this for hours now but it just doesn't work. My best solution (that still doesn't work) was

1. creating a resource folder
2. add it to the Build path
3. putting all library-jars in it

When I export the project this way and open it on another machine, the jars are still there but nevertheless none of the references/imports to these libraries can be resolved...what am I missing?

**EDIT**: [This is my .classpath file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y3vO.png)

The errors I get are not too interesting - they're just import that cannot be resolved.

Comment: If you used in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, in the tab _Libraries_ the button _Add JARs..._ and not _Add External JARs..._ it should work. Otherwise, show us the `.classpath` file (which is visible in the _Navigatior_ view) and the errors you get.

Comment: I edited my post to contain the information you needed. I use the "Add JARs" but it doesn't work.

Comment: On the target machine, which errors are shown in the _Problems_ view (are there also build path errors)? Which JREs/JDKs have configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ on the target machine?

Comment: When you say "open it on another machine", what exactly are you doing? If you've exported the project to an Archive file (a .zip file) then you have to import the project into another eclipse using the Import>General>Existing Projects into Workspace wizard and select the Select Archive File option. Remember that you've exported an eclipse project, so the imported project should be the same, with the same .project and .classpath files that you exported. It's difficult to see how that would result in the problems you see unless you're not importing into eclipse.